# Is it possible to run a Cookiecutter template file without creating the local folder?

Tags: cookiecutter

When I use cookiecutter, especially in the first phases of the project, I find myself debugging the instantiated copy of the template, finding the problem, and then having to go back to the template to fix it there as well.

This all feels redundant, and I feel that if it was possible to run the template files without physically coping them and instantiating them everytime I change something would make the development much faster.

Is there any way to test the cookiecutter template files without instantiating the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this otherwise and there is a good reason to be that way: The errors, you may find, may be just errors in your code, but may be caused by the values, provided by the user, or the defaults you provided in the cookiecutter.json, or the way you use those in your templates...

What I do in your situation is the following:
I don't template my project at the very beginning. I am writing the code just the way it is without cookiecutter. On the way, I am writing down notes what I want to put in the template. I am marking what should be turned into variable, what should be the default value, variable file and foldernames, etc.

When I am done with my bootstrap and I think it is good enough to fire version 1.0, I start templating it after my notes and then test the template one more time to ensure that I haven't missed something.

Yes, after that point, you will have to evolve the template and you won't be able to avoid this redundant testing, but it is not so intensive as at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to approach every project from an automation standpoint. Here we can use a testing pattern.

I have a cookiecutter project with a `{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}` source directory raring to go.

I can clone that repository 'bare' to another directory and then I can use Cookiecutter on the bare repository. This could get expensive, but there are ways to limit the information. Example below in accompanying source with tests.

I *also* have a `src` directory with:

```
.\src\
     \main.py
     \test_main.py
```

### `main.py`

```py
"""Deploy the project."""
import click
from cookiecutter.main import cookiecutter


def make_project(repo_folder, output_folder, no_input):
    cookiecutter(
        template=repo_folder,
        checkout=None,
        no_input=no_input,  # If test name isn't empty, run this without input.
        extra_context=None,
        replay=None,
        overwrite_if_exists=False,
        output_dir=output_folder,
        config_file=None,
        default_config=False,
        password=None,
        directory=None,
        skip_if_file_exists=False,
        accept_hooks=True,
        keep_project_on_failure=False
    )

@click.command()
@click.option('--repo-folder', prompt='Cookiecutter folder', help='The source code.')
@click.option('--output-folder', prompt='Output folder', help='Compiled project.')
@click.option('--test', prompt='Declare a test', help='Run a test.')
def main(repo_folder, output_folder, test):
    click.echo(f'Deploying project from: {repo_folder}')
    click.echo(f'Deploying project to: {output_folder}')
    click.echo(f'Test Execution: {test}')
    make_project(repo_folder=repo_folder, output_folder=output_folder, no_input=len(test))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

### `test_main.py`

```py
import os
import subprocess
from main import make_project

def test_deployment():
    import tempfile
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as t:
        print("Cloning the local into a temp bare workspace.")
        os.environ["COOKIECUTTER_CONFIG"] = "src/test_config.yml"
        subprocess.run(f"git clone --bare file:///workspaces/RunAThing {t}/repo.git", shell=True)
        # It *must* be specified with a full file schema.
        make_project(f'file://{t}/repo.git', f'{t}/test', no_input=True)
        raise Exception(os.listdir(f'{t}/test/run-a-thing'))
```

Now, I can run the project through pytest pretty quickly. Then I can put all sorts of tests in that test deployment function like 'has the right structure / files / whatever'.

This still *technically* makes the local folder, but it's completely ephemeral and gets cleaned up when pytest is done running.

`python -m pytest -s src/test_main.py`

Makes pretty good documentation, too.